# Why has my neighbor city stopped taking garbage?

Tags: simcity-4

I have two cities. **1st** is the *main*. **2nd** is for garbage export. It was not difficult to start garbage exporting. I just created road connection and placed garbage processing plant in the 2nd and a 2x2 garbage area. I was exporting up to 80 garbage successfully, but then export was broken. When I'm cliking on "Neighbor deals", I get "There are currently no neighbor deals available" and can't do nothing. Also I still can't import/export Power (I've already built powerlines connection).

I have a nice city with 7000 population and it will begin die in few months if I would not start exporting garbage again. But now I don't know how.

Comment: Does your neighbour city still have enough space in the landfill to take your garbage? Try putting in more landfill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things that can cause a deal to be canceled:

- The Customer (the one with the trash) does not have a minimum amount of money in the bank.

  Something like twice the cities TOTAL budget for a month. If you're out of money, your only option is loading from where you saved the city last, or taking out a loan. I have had this kill cities before.
- Service Provider (the one burning the trash) does not have enough capacity.

  Note that when you are playing as the Customer, the Service Provider's info is locked in: the capacity for each month and the total trash collected DO NOT CHANGE no matter how many months you play as the Customer. This means there's no chance the Service Provider's land fills are full, but rather that the customer is making too much trash each month for the Service Provider to take.
- The connection is broken.

  Simple enough, the roads/powerlines/pipes have been demolished due to a mis-click or disaster or something.

In any of these cases, the deal is canceled automatically. You will have to open both cities, check that everything is OK, THEN re-initiate the deal. Also, I believe you sometimes have to run a month in either city for any correction you've made (such as building more landfill) to be recognized, and allow you to restart the deal.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was in that once I spent all my money. Later I had the same thing 2 or 3 times. When your money run below deal size, it breaks, and then you need to wait until get several thousands of money to remake deal. Also, there is a *notfication* — you can read in news smth. like "... no more interested in your garbage."

Comment: @Nakilon Yeah, I remember the message now. There's just so much noise in the ticker/full news screen that I just trained myself watch all the graphs closely and find all the problems for myself, to the point I even forget I could do it the other way. :( Sorry for the error.