# Why can't I buy electricity from an electricity -rich neighbour city in SimCity 4?

Tags: simcity-4

1. I've built a usual city.
2. I've built a new city with redundant power production right near the first one.
3. I've initiated a deal to sell power to the first city successfully.
4. I've started a new city right near the second one planning to buy electricity from it (I've even built intercity power line connection and taken care to connect the power lines on the both sides).
5. But the deal to trade power between the second and the third cities is not available (does not appear in the list).

Why?

Comment: You might also want to look at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/why-has-my-neighbor-city-stopped-taking-garbage

Answer (score 0):

As I recall until your city-that-will-be-buying reaches an electricity deficit, the deal to buy electricity from your city-that-will-be-selling will not appear. Once your sims cry out for the need for power, you should receive a notification giving you the option to make the deal.

Comment: First I've didn't built any own power plants at all, just some zones connected with power lines to the neighbouring city. And all the zones were indicated as unpowered. Then I've built some windtraps as a bootstrap power source and did actually receive the notice of need of more power. And still no option to make the deal.

Comment: Odd. You got me stumped. I stopped playing SC4 after I discovered there isn't an 'end game' (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79594/does-sim-city-4-blow-up-at-any-point) So beyond what I've mentioned I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Hey just saw this question, maybe its a dupe, or maybe it will help you. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86900/how-to-trade-power-between-cities